# Vuejs page won't load when dynamic router link is clicked

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router, laravel-7

I'm using VueJs 2 with Laravel 7. I have the following code which should swap out a dynamically created page when you click next or previous. It will change the URL perfectly fine but the page won't change and I'm not sure where I went wrong.

Here are the links:

```
 <div class="row">
     <div class="col-4 offset-2">              
         <router-link :to="{name: 'question', params: {question: index -1  }, query: {question: index - 1 }}">
             <div v-if="index > 0" class="btn btn-primary">Previous</div>
         </router-link>
     </div>
     <div class="col-4">
         <router-link :to="{name: 'question', params: {question: index + 1 }, query: {question: index + 1 }}">
             <div v-if="index < questions.length" class="btn btn-primary">Next</div>
         </router-link>
     </div>
 </div>
```

The router tag:

```js
<router-view            
     :key="$route.params.question"
     :index="pageNumber + 1"
     :header="header" 
     :questions="questions" 
     v-on:sectionScore="sectionScoreChange"
     :colour="colours[index % colours.length]"
     >
</router-view>
```

The route in web.php

```
Route::get('/{any?}', 'QuestionnaireController@index')->where('any', '.*');
```

and finally the route in vue router:

```js
const routes = [
  {
    path: '/question/:question',
    name: 'question',
    component: Questions,    
  }
];
```

If it helps, when you click the router links to change the URL and press refresh, it will indeed swap the page, it just doesn't do it automatically.

Comment: Does it mean that if you click "previous" button, it doesn't go to another page?

Comment: Correct, it (and the next button) will only update the URL but the page doesn't move

Comment: maybe, if you refresh the page, then the page will be displayed, right?

Comment: I can't be 100% certain, but it seems like you're using the same component to serve the data, so you'll need to bind a unique key to the `router-view` to ensure the component is refreshed on navigation: `:key="$route.fullPath"` should do it.

Comment: Still doesn't do it until I refresh manually I'm afraid

Comment: How would you type in the URL? (E.g. `/question/1`) How does your URL look like if the button click generates it? `/question/:question` ≠ `/question/?question=`

Comment: I removed the query part of the original code so the URL looks like /question/1 in the address bar

Comment: You should have more knowledge about SPA. If you use "href" tag instead of router-link, that would be worked

Comment: I think it would be helpful to see the Questions component.  Specifically, what mechanism does this component use to extract the question parameter and render the correct content?